# Passing dropdown value to PHP variable (without submit using jQuery)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am building a pizza ordering form that calculates form fields depends on user choices and returns the total.
The first input will be the currency drop down, once user selects currency, it should pass value to PHP variable $currency (so that it will calculate the exchange rate)
without the need to submit the form of course.

I have seen a lot of similar codes, but got confused, I know I should be using JavaScript / Ajax, but my knowledge is weak in that.

Can you please paste a simple code that will pass the $currency value to PHP?

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
    $("#currency").change(function(){
        var selected_value = $(this).val();
        /*AJAX CODE HERE TO PASS VALUE OF DROP DOWN TO PHP*/
        $.post("CurrencyCalculator.php", $("#currency").serialize()); //this is the problematic part: it needs to pass the $currency variable
    })

})
</script>
</head>
<body>
Select any one: 
<select id="currency" name="currency" onchange="selectDropdown()">
<option value="EUR" >Euro</option>
<option value="USD" >US Dollar</option>
<option value="GBP" >British Pound</option>
</select>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how much will get for this ? have you checked http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Comment: Have you read the jQuery documentation? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ would be a good place to start.

Comment: I am aware that the answer is here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ but i am not able to figure out still :)

Comment: what part of it are you having trouble with?

Comment: I have just pasted the peace of sample code

Comment: `$.post('CurrencyCalculator.php', { dropdown_value: selected_value }, function(data) { //do something here });` should do the trick. On the PHP side, use `$_POST['dropdown_value']` to get the value. The `//do something here` part is where you'd do something with a return value if you'd like. Check [the jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for more.

Comment: @NullPointer somehow I doubt he's actually writing a real pizza order site where users can pay in three different currencies (does the shop deliver to multiple countries ?). It's probably homework. ;)

Comment: @NullPointer you are half right :) its not for a pizza :P (but actually, for example in Hungary you pay in Hungarian forints, while you should accept euro as well since its in the EU.

Comment: the pizza is a classic example of a more complex idea, just for the sake to simplify  my pizza case is a perfect example :)

Comment: @sgroves i tried your code, didn't work :( once i send the value of currency to the php file, it has if statement (if USD then calculate the price) where after prices showing in the form will change

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Do you want to pass the type of currency too (EUR, USD, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Php is run on the server before the HTML is returned to the browser.  You cannot pass a value from an html form to a php variable for this reason.

You can, however, submit a form to a php page for processing.

```
<form action="myPhpPage.php">
```

Then inside of myPhpPage.php you can use $_GET['variableName'] to retrieve the value

Comment: hmm but thats the point, i do not wish to make an additional submit button in the form.

Comment: i have tried your methoud, problem is its going to "myPhpPage.php?currency=USD" insead of just reloading the same form page to continue - so the target is that once selected, page is not submited nor reloaded this needs jquery / java ajax code :(

Answer (score 0):

Since its a drop down menu where the currency is selected, give the menu an `onchange` attribute and send the info to your PHP file to process it.

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(function($){
  $("#currency").change(function(){
   var selected_value = $(this).val();
   /*AJAX CODE HERE TO PASS VALUE OF DROP DOWN TO PHP*/
   $.post("t3.php", $("#currency").serialize()); //something like this??
  })
  
 })
</script>
</head>
<body>
Select any one: 
<select id="currency" name="currency" onchange="selectDropdown()">
<option value="EUR" >Euro</option>
<option value="USD" >US Dollar</option>
</select>

Comment: I do not know jQuery or how you want your ajax code to look, but a very (note:very) basic way of submitting this data when the drop down menu is used is this:
`<?php

$currency = $_REQUEST['currency']

echo $currency

?>



<html>
<form name="mainform" action="" method="post">
<select name="currency" onchange="this.form.submit()">
<option value="eur">Euro</option>
<option value="usd">USD</option>
</select>
</form>
</html>`

Comment: hmm not quite, since this will post all the form. the drop down function is to change price value withen the form (which is done in seperate php file, so all i need is to bypass the value of $currency to the included php file

Comment: @user1741397 You could put the select object in a separate form and store the value sent from it in a PHP session variable to use it in the external PHP file. Just make a form containing the `<select>` and make a second form containing the rest, with two different names obviously.

Comment: this sounds more logical, how do i make the session? :-)

Comment: @user1741397 Instead of defining your curreny variable in PHP as `$currency = $_REQUEST['currency']` simply put `$_SESSION['currency'] = $_REQUEST['currency']` instead :) Remember though that you MUST put `session_start()` right after the `<?php` tag in EVERY document that uses session variables!

Comment: i have tried it, still it would submit the form once selected from drop down

Comment: What are the names of your forms? Say the form containing only the `<select>` is called `name="selectform"` and the form containing the actual data is called `name="mainform"`. In the `<select>` tag, set `onchange="document.forms['selectform'].submit()"`

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into $_POST and $_GET

```
<?php

if(($_POST['submit']))
{

    // do your stuff
}

?>

<form action="something" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Vote!">
</form>
```

when this form is pressed, the phpp code will be run